# How can I add a reset and restart to this when a button is pressed after the game is over?

Tags: java, processing

I am trying to write this code in processing. A Connect Four game uses an Arduino as a controller for each row.

After a winner is detected, the game stops. But I want to make the game reset the table and restart after any button is pushed, and the problem is I am not sure how to do that.

Thanks in advance!

Here's the code:

```
//Connect Four Game
//Mohammed Sharifpour
//2nd of February, 2022

import processing.serial.*;

Serial ADP;

int squareSize = 64;
String serialName = "COM6";   //Can be modified to the indicated COM Port 

color pc[] = {color(255, 75,0), color(48, 213, 200)};
String PCN[] = {"Orange", "Turqoise"};
int playerTurn = 0;

int grid[][] = new int[7][8];
boolean finished = false;

color backgroundColor = color(0, 0, 0);
color lineColor = color(255, 255, 255);


void Circle(int x, int y, color c){
  fill(c);
  noStroke();
  circle(x * squareSize + 0.5 * squareSize, y * squareSize + 0.5 * squareSize, squareSize);
}

void draw(){
  if (ADP.available() > 0) keypressed(ADP.read()-1);
}

void printText(String message){
  fill(backgroundColor);
  noStroke();
  rect(0, 6 * squareSize + 1, 7 * squareSize + 1, (6 + 1) * squareSize + 1);
  fill(lineColor);
  text(message, 16, 6 * squareSize + squareSize * 0.75);
}

void setup(){
  size(480, 480);
  noCursor();
  background(backgroundColor);
  stroke(lineColor);
  for(int x = 0; x <= 7 * squareSize; x += squareSize){
    line(x, 0, x, 6 * squareSize);
  }
  for(int y = 0; y <= 6 * squareSize; y += squareSize){
    line(0, y, 7 * squareSize, y);
  }
  //RGB Code for Circle "Orange" (255, 75,0);
  //RGB Code for Circle "Turqoise" (48, 213, 200);

  printArray(Serial.list());
  ADP = new Serial(this, serialName, 9600);
  
  textSize(squareSize / 4);
  printText("Welcome to Connect Four, press any button to start!");
}



boolean handleDrop(int column){
  boolean dropped = false;
  for(int y = 6 - 1; y >= 0; y--){
    if(grid[column][y] == 0){
      grid[column][y] = playerTurn;
      Circle(column, y, pc[playerTurn - 1]);
      dropped = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  return dropped;
}

void keypressed(int bs){
  if(bs < 2 || bs > 7 + 1) return;
  if(finished) return;
  boolean dropped = false;
  if(playerTurn > 0){
    dropped = handleDrop(bs - 2);
    if(!dropped) return;
  }
  playerTurn++;
  if(playerTurn > 2) playerTurn = 1;
  int winner = testWinner();
  if(winner > 0){
    finished = true;
    textSize(squareSize / 3);
    printText(PCN[winner - 1] + " won!, GAME OVER");
    return;
  }
  printText(PCN[playerTurn - 1] + "'s turn");
}

int testFour(int startX, int startY, int incX, int incY){
  int box = -1;
  for(int x = startX, y = startY, i = 0; i < 4; x += incX, y += incY, i++){
    if(box < 0){
      box = grid[x][y];
    }else{
      if(grid[x][y] != box) return 0;
    }
  }
  if(box > 0){
    int startXPixel = startX * squareSize + squareSize / 2;
    int startYPixel = startY * squareSize + squareSize / 2;
    stroke(lineColor);
    strokeWeight(4);
    line(startXPixel, startYPixel, startXPixel + 3 * incX * squareSize, startYPixel + 3 * incY * squareSize);
  }
  return box;
}

int testWinner(){
  int winner = 0;
  for(int x = 0; x < 7  - 3; x++){
    for(int y = 0; y < 6 ; y++){
      winner = testFour(x, y, 1, 0);
      if(winner > 0) return winner;
    }
  }
  for(int y = 0; y <6 - 3; y++){
    for(int x = 0; x < 7; x++){
      winner = testFour(x, y, 0, 1);
      if(winner > 0) return winner;
    }
  }
  for(int x = 0; x < 7 - 3; x++){
    for(int y = 0; y < 6 - 3; y++){
      winner = testFour(x, y, 1, 1);
      if(winner > 0) return winner;
    }
  }
  for(int x = 0; x < 7 - 3; x++){
    for(int y = 6 - 1; y >= 3; y--){
      winner = testFour(x, y, 1, -1);
      if(winner > 0) return winner;
    }
  }
  return winner;
}
```

Comment: What you have tried so far, and what were the results of that??

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet, because I am confused as to how I can get the screen to reset.

Comment: Re-write your code so that you can attach it with a loop, which clears the array or results after the winner is decided.

Comment: will do, thanks!

Comment: Okay, no problem